# Microsoft office render engine keeps underlining anchor tags (HTML email)

Tags: html, outlook

I want to make a HTML email signature for a client. I have a couple of link that go to their website and instagram. I want the links to appear as normal text.  I used `text-underline: none !important;` and this seems to work for apple mail and gmail. The Outlook render engine, however keeps underlining the text. I tried using HTML conditionals for MSO:

`<!--[if gte mso 9]> <style> text-decoration: none !important; </style> <![endif]-->`

I googled a long time to search for a solution, but i can't find anything that works :(.

Is there anyone that can help me?